# Boost asio deadline timer completing immediately (C++)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

The code below prints "connected" to the console immediately, as opposed to after 10s. Why is this? Is it to do with the way I'm passing my `print` callback?

```
void print(const boost::system::error_code& e) {
  std::cout << "connected!" << std::endl;
}

class WebSocketSession {
 public:
  WebSocketSession(asio::io_context &io_context) : io_context_(io_context) {}
  void connect() {
    boost::asio::deadline_timer
        timer(io_context_, boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
    timer.async_wait(&print);
  }
 private:
  asio::io_context &io_context_;
};

class WebSocketClient {
 public:
  WebSocketClient(asio::io_context &io_context) : io_context_(io_context) {}
  std::unique_ptr<WebSocketSession> exec() {
    auto session = std::make_unique<WebSocketSession>(io_context_);
    session->connect();
    return session;
  }
 private:
  asio::io_context &io_context_;
};

int main() {
  asio::io_context io_context;
  WebSocketClient client{io_context};
  std::unique_ptr<WebSocketSession> session = client.exec();
  io_context.run();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `deadline_timer` cannot be local variable, because `async_wait` returns immediately, so timer is destroyed at the end of function scope.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I still don't understand why the callback is invoked despite the timer being destroyed?

Comment: callback is called to inform you that some error happened. Look at reference of [deadline_timer dtor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/_basic_deadline_timer.html).

Comment: ah I see. thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `deadline_timer` is destroyed too soon because it's a local variable, thus canceling the I/O operation.

If we add some error handling, we will see the actual error reported:

```
void print(const boost::system::error_code& e) {
    if (e.failed())
        std::cout << "error: " << e.message() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "connected!" << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

`error: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request`

A possible fix is to move `deadline_timer` to be member of `WebSocketSession`:

```
class WebSocketSession {
public:
    WebSocketSession(boost::asio::io_context& io_context) : io_context_(io_context),
        timer_(io_context, boost::posix_time::seconds(10)) {}
    void connect() {
        timer_.async_wait(&print);
    }
private:
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
};
```